# Bind TextChangedEvent to ListView object

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms PCL project where it has a list of messages and each message has an entry to enter data for it. I would like to add a label under the entry that would count down the characters left from 50. For example, if they type "test" it would do 50 - the length of the text.

I tried tracking text changed with this code but It kept causing an invalid cast error so I haven't got further

```
private void ReplyTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var message = sender as MessageObject;
    }
```

The XAML is

```
<StackLayout>
        <ListView  x:Name="MessageView">
            <ListView .ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:PostViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                             <StackLayout x:Name="MessageLayout" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="10, 10, 15, 10">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" IsVisible="{Binding ShowReplyField}" Spacing="0">
                                      <Entry Text="{Binding ReplyText}" Placeholder="Reply..." TextChanged="ReplyTextChanged" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0, 0, 0, 5"/>
                                      <Label Text="{Binding TextLeft}"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </local:PostViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
```

My message object is

```
public class MessageObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string idValue = "";
    private string bodyValue = "";
    private string replyTextLeftValue = "";
    . . .

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private MessageObject(string id, string body, . . .)
    {
        idValue = id;
        bodyValue = body;
        replyTextLeftValue = "50 Characters";
        . . . 
    }

    public static MessageObject CreateMessage(string id, string body, . . .)
    {
        return new MessageObject(string id, string body, . . .);
    }

    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idValue;
        }
    }

    public string Body
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bodyValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this.bodyValue)
            {
                this.bodyValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public string TextLeft
    {
        get
        {
            return this.replyTextLeftValue;
        }

        set
        {
            if(value != this.replyTextLeftValue)
            {
                this.replyTextLeftValue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can create converter for calculate remaring symbols. Also binding context for label must be reference for entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the TextChanged event handler, sender is going to be the Entry that is raising the event, not the view model object, which is why you're seeing that error.  You can reference the model via the BindingContext.

Assuming that MessageObject.TextLeft is set up to fire a property changed event (you don't show the entire MessageObject class), then the TextChanged event handler would look something like:

```
private void ReplyTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var message = BindingContext as MessageObject;
        message.TextLeft = 50 - e.NewTextValue.Length;
    }
```

**EDIT**

To summarize the follow-up comments, an alternative is to avoid using the TextChanged callback completely, and instead implement the ReplyText and TextLeft properties on MessageObject as such:

```
public string TextLeft 
{ 
  get 
  { 
    return this.replyTextLeftValue; 
  } 
} 

public string ReplyText 
{ 
  get 
  { 
    return this.replyTextValue; 
  } 

  set 
  { 
    if(value != this.replyTextValue) 
    { 
      this.replyTextValue = value; 
      this.replyTextLeftValue = (50 - value.Length).ToString(); 
      NotifyPropertyChanged(); 
      NotifyPropertyChanged("TextLeft"); 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: That worked to an extent, but when I tried (for testing) changing the body it said _NInterpret.NInterpretException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>_ on the body's set method which I'm guessing it is since there is no CommandParameter field? Do you know a fix to this?

Comment: Can you add in the entire MessageObject implementation?

Comment: What type has the ReplyText and TextLeft properties that are used in the ItemTemplate Bindings?  It doesn't look like it's MessageObject...

Comment: Oops my bad, I edited it in. But no matter what I change in the TextChanged method it generates an error

Comment: How is ReplyText defined?

Comment: It's based on what they type in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169049/discussion-between-davids-and-dan).